# Почему gulp не обновляет все файлы html?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Почему пишу так:

```js
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  watch('./app/*.html', gulp.parallel( bs.reload ))
})
```

и он не обновляет страницы при изменении
А когда пишу так:

```js
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  watch('./app/index.html', gulp.parallel( bs.reload ))
}) то так обновляет файл, что я не так делаю выше?
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в `gulp.parallel( bs.reload )`, функция выполняется только 1 раз, т.к. `bs.reload()` не предназначена для прямой передачи в `gulp.parallel`.

В [документации](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/parallel#usage) описана структура функции передаваемой в `gulp.parallel`:

```
function foo(done) {
  // тело функции
  done(); // Говорим gulp что функция выполнена
}
```

---

**Решение 1:**

Обернуть `bs.reload()` в функцию:

```
function reloadBrowser(done){
    bs.reload();
    done();
}

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./app/*.html', gulp.parallel( reloadBrowser ));
})
```

---

**Решение 2:**

Использовать `watch().on("change", callback)`

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./app/*.html').on("change", bs.reload);
})
```

Comment: Может что-то я не так делаю или я всё так сделал и у меня не работает)
Перепробовал оба варианта, не работает
const gulp = require('gulp');
const bs = require('browser-sync').create();
const watch = require('gulp-watch');

function reloadBrowser(done) {
  bs.reload();
  done();
}

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch(['./app/*.html','./app/css/**/*.css'], gulp.parallel(reloadBrowser));
}); 

gulp.task('server', function () {
  bs.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./app/"
    }
  })
})

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('server','watch'));

Comment: @DmitriyRudenko Ваш пример у меня полностью работает